# Uploading .MOV files with carrierwave-video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, carrierwave

Issue: I am unable to upload .mov files via Carrierwave.

I have no issue with carrier wave with uploading images, and for video - .mp4 files.  When i attempt to upload .mov files, the upload fails.  I'm assuming anything other than .mp4 will not work.

Anyone use Carrierwave-video gem and are able to upload .mov file format?

**My carrierwave gems:**

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'carrierwave-ffmpeg'
gem 'carrierwave-video'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
```

**I tried using:**

```
 version :mp4 do
   process encode_video: [:mp4]
 end

 version :mov do
   process encode_video: [:mov]
 end
```

in my uploader with and without if statements before the `version...` but not working.  With either, i am unable to upload either `mov` or `mp4`

**By default i have in my uploader:**

```
  process encode_video: [:mp4]
```

And this allows me to upload only .mp4 files with success to `aws`

When i do:

```
  process encode_video: [:mov]
```

I get the error when trying `mp4` or `mov`:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

Whitelisted:

```
def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png mov mp4 mov avi mkv 3gp mpg mpeg)
  end
```

I also tried simply changing the .mov file to .mp4 and didn't work.

**Has anyone here had success uploading mov files?**

I worry because i know iPhones output most video files in .mov format so it's pretty important to allow this format.

Errors:

```
When trying to upload mov file i do get this success in the prompt:
I, [2019-01-20T02:47:51.127532 #3483]  INFO -- : Transcoding of /home/bob/Apps/app-file-master/tmp/1547970464-3483-0025-9410/samplemov.mov to /home/bob/Apps/uploader-twitter-master/tmp/1547970464-3483-0025-9410/tmpfile.mp4 succeeded
```

but then the upload fail and doesn't save into the DB or AWS.  No where within my app at all.  I checked the file it says it succeeded into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started debugging my uploader file and found the reason why mov were unable to upload.

I previously had this:

```
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::FFmpeg
```

I removed `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ".mov" to carrierwave's extension white list in its config file.

Comment: I updated the OP.  and added my whitelist list.  Its already in there.

Comment: and to note, none of the whitelists work.  only mp4's are able to be uploaded somehow

Comment: Usually I've used separate uploaders for image and video (config was slightly different as I recall). Can you provide full content of your Uploader file? And you get NilError because you're trying to add video path to sth else right? You can provide full stack trace - it might help out.

Comment: I do use seperate uploaders for videos and images.  I just have the  images listed their by default.  Are you able to uplod .mov with carreierwave?

Comment: hey so it ended up being `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick` that was causing the issue.  Not sure why it does as of yet (will read into the docs now) but once removed, it works.